# Cannot decrypt with iv as plain text AES

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have logic that works perfectly in C# for encrypting and decrypting text using AES CBC 128 Bit

Now I have a problem where the other party cannot decrypt the text and nor can this site:
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

How can I get the IV into a version that can be used to decrypt outside of C#?

I tried

```
stream  = encryptionInfo.InversionVectorText.ToMemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII);
```

also

```
stream  = encryptionInfo.InversionVectorText.ToMemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8);
```

Neither of these give me a value that I can paste into the site above and have work

The other side want me to send the IV in plain text

My full code is below for reference:

```
public static class SecurityExtensions
{
    private static Aes GetAes(string keyText, byte[] iv)
    {
        var key = keyText.ToByteArray();
        var result = Aes.Create();
        result.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        result.KeySize = 128;
        if (iv.Length > 0)
        {
            result.IV = iv;
        }

        result.Key = key;

        return result;
    }

    private static string GenerateRandomCryptoString(int length, string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890")
    {
        using (var crypto = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var result = crypto.GenerateRandomCryptoString(length, charset);
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static string GenerateRandomCryptoString(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider random, 
        int length, 
        string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890") =>
        RandomString(random.GetBytes, length, charset.ToCharArray());

    private static string RandomString(Action<byte[]> fillRandomBuffer, int length, char[] charset)
    {
        var maxIdx = charset.Length;
        var chars = new char[length];
        var randomBuffer = new byte[length * 4];
        fillRandomBuffer(randomBuffer);

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            chars[i] = charset[BitConverter.ToUInt32(randomBuffer, i * 4) % maxIdx];

        var result = new string(chars);
        return result;
    }

    public static AesEncryptionInfo EncryptWithAes(this string plainText, string keyText)
    {
        //Generate an IV made up of only alphanumeric characters to avoid encoding/decoding issues
        var ivText = GenerateRandomCryptoString(16);
        var iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ivText); 
        var aesAlg = GetAes(keyText, iv);
        var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        byte[] encrypted;
        using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }

        aesAlg.Dispose();
        

        var result = new AesEncryptionInfo(encrypted, aesAlg.IV);
        return result;
    }

    public static string DecryptFromAes(this byte[] cipherText, string keyText, byte[] iv)
    {
        string result;
        var aesAlg = GetAes(keyText, iv);
        var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class AesEncryptionInfo
{
    public AesEncryptionInfo(byte[] encrypted, byte[] inversionVector)
    {
        InversionVector = inversionVector;
        Encrypted = encrypted;

    }

    public byte[] InversionVector { get; set; }
    public byte[] Encrypted { get; set; }
    public string InversionVectorText => Encoding.Default.GetString(InversionVector);
}
```

The other side are adamant they do not want to do any kind of decoding, which is obviously not a good approach!

So I have some code that generates a random 16 character string of numbers or letters.  This definitely generates a string of 16 characters.

When I decrypt this using the logic above the text is decrypted correctly, but I also see random characters at the start.  I dont know why this happens?

Comment: Here's a [hint](https://rextester.com/XCDMY13686) at what I suspect your problem is.

Comment: Did you put the right IV in the website you tested with?
Looks like it expects the IV as a string of hex characters.

Comment: The website expects 16 characters for the IV, which indicates a charset encoding (like UTF8). Since IVs generally consist of arbitrary binary data, they are not compatible with such encodings. So the website can only handle a fraction of all possible IVs and is an example of a flawed crypto website. An IV should be exported in a binary-to-text encoding such as Base64 or Hex, and a decent crypto website should also support such encodings, e.g. https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef.

Comment: The other side are adamant that they want me to send the iv as plain text when they decrypted the iv I gave them they reckon it’s 27 bytes when it’s supposed to be 16 what do I do?

Comment: If possible, you should Base64 encode your IV and the other side should Base64 decode it (i.e. the other side should change their encoding). Otherwise, find out the encoding used by the other side for the IV (possibly UTF8) and create an IV compatible with it. You can pass this IV in the 2nd parameter of `GetAES()`. Note that the IV _implicitly_ generated by your code is an _arbitrary_ byte array and is not compatible with UTF8.

Comment: They just want plain ascii.  I tried to generate my own IV from a guid taking the first 16 characters but that fails in the encryption.  The other side do not want to do any decoding of the IV

Comment: Then create a random IV whose bytes are compatible with ASCII. If you send this as a string to the other side, you should limit yourself to the printable characters. The other side should, however, take a basic course in encoding and crypto.

Comment: Every combination I try doesnt generate the correct size byte array.  I tried to generate a 16 character random string but the call to convert it to a byte array gives an array that is 20 bytes??  I have updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232384/discussion-between-topaco-and-paul).